# Windows Storing php sessions in C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1

Tags: php, session

I have an issue a user reported where they could not login. I wasn't able to get the exact error message but somehow the session file was not being created. It started working again randomly.

I am storing sessions in: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1

Is there any problem with storing sessions there? I have never run across this problem where it randomly didn't work and then seemed to fix itself.

The user has 400GB + of free space.

Comment: Are you using a default package like WAMPP or XAMPP?

Comment: No, I am using a custom developed Bitnami stack and we wanted to store sessions in a safe place for windows and am just wondering if there is a problem there?

Comment: Is it possible the user tried to log in using a non-privileged user?

Comment: Nope. They were logged in as the administrator. The stack runs as an admin and they only had one user account.

Comment: If you have a development environment the first step would be wisest to install that same custom package on another Windows system and test if the session problem arises there too with some simple logins/actions. If not then it might simply be a corrupted session and you should just remove it (with the repercussion that everyone will probably be logged out). The final step will likely be something you do with your code, but its always pretty hard to determine without seeing it.

Comment: Maybe there was no such path for session? Not all windows has user as "Administrator". And what if he is using Linux? Or Windows installed on D disc?

Comment: You are correct. Tho its better to throw some possible redundant input than none at all :)

Comment: The installer packaged provided by bit rock does this:
`<setInstallerVariable name="component(php).parameter(php_tmp_dir).value" value="${system_temp_directory}"/>` So it creates the path on the fly when installing

Comment: I am unable to reproduce on a development machine and this happened for about 1 hour after 3 weeks of it hot happening. It almost seems like something is deleting files from that folder. I wasn't able to get into the machine until it started working again. The basic question is does anything delete from that folder automatically?

Comment: Well it *is* is a temp-folder. You might consider pointing your application to a safer location (for storing data) where no cleanup or process touches it.

Comment: @Allendar I want the files to be cleaned up eventually. But my question is if there is anything that modifies this folder.